# Nested if statements in MVC partial view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a bootstrap nav bar dynamically into a partial view. Every thing seems to work fine for the top level menus, but when I add code to loop through to find and add child items Razor seems to not like it very much.

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.ParentID == null))
        {
            <li name="@item.menusID" class="">
                <a href="#">@item.text</a>
                @foreach (var childItem in Model.Where(x => x.ParentID.Equals(item.menusID)))
                {
                    if (Model.Where(x => x.ParentID.Equals(item.menusID)).First() == childItem)
                    {
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#">@childItem.text</a></li>
                    }
                    else if (Model.Where(x => x.ParentID.Equals(item.menusID)).Last() == childItem) @*Problem here*@
                    {
                        <li><a href="#">@childItem.text</a></li></ul>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li><a href="#">@childItem.text</a></li>
                    }
                }

            </li>
        }
```

The code above does not recognize the else if in the center where I try and find the last item in the list to close of the `<ul>` and end the dropdown section. If I remove the HTML from the whole if else if else statement there is no error and it seems to run. I even tried using multiple if statements instead of the else but no luck, this seemed to be even worse then what I had. I know I could just run this code in the controller and send it as a viewbag, but I would like to know what is wrong, did I miss something? Some post I read suggested the use of `<text>` tags but I can't see it working with this code as I am building lists and not text blocks.

Comment: Why not just `<ul> @foreach(...){ <li><a href="#">@childItem.text</a></li> } </ul>`

Comment: `Razer seems to not like it very much.` can you elaborate on this?

Comment: just move the `<ul>`and  `</ul>` out of loop, ie  with all always have a start and end. no need to factor this in the logic

Comment: Thanks Kumar. looking at it from a different angle it makes sense to do it that way! For the code I sent the "else if" line turns white in VS2017 and when I run the code it adds the actual else if as text and not code? This and it loses some close tags to HTML elements? Why I do not know?